# unable to convert WSDL to Apex, getting Error: Failed to parse wsdl: targetNamespace not specified in wsdl:definitions

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex

[image]

below is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
        <wsse:Username>apiuser</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">December@2018</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <bm:createTransaction xmlns:bm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cpqcloud/commerce/oraclecpqo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <bm:transaction>
        <bm:process_var_name>oraclecpqo</bm:process_var_name>
        <bm:_bm_cm_new_transaction_currency/>
        <bm:return_specific_attributes>
          <bm:documents>
            <bm:document>
              <bm:var_name>transaction</bm:var_name>
              <bm:attributes>
                <bm:attribute>_document_number</bm:attribute>
                <bm:attribute>transactionID_t</bm:attribute>
              </bm:attributes>
            </bm:document>
          </bm:documents>
        </bm:return_specific_attributes>
      </bm:transaction>
    </bm:createTransaction>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: did you tried to parse the wsdl with soap UI does it able to generate the stub?

Comment: wsdl starts with wsdl [<wsdl:definitions ... ]  this is a soap request

Comment: Can you share the complete WSDL?